# Update based on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this following table (Employees) :

```
EmployeeId WorkingForId WorkingFor
34         45           NULL
34         66           NULL
34         78           NULL
```

I want to update the WorkingFor column based on another table (Companies) like below :

```
CompanyId Name
45        SONY
66        HP
78        MICROSOFT
99        APPLE
```

So my expected output will be like below :

```
EmployeeId WorkingForId WorkingFor
    34         45       SONY
    34         66       HP
    34         78       MICROSOFT
```

You can create this table by code below :

```
CREATE TABLE employees
    ([EmployeeId] int, [WorkingForId] int, [WorkingFor] varchar(40))
;

INSERT INTO employees
    ([EmployeeId], [WorkingForId], [WorkingFor])
VALUES
    (34, 45, NULL),
    (34, 66, NULL),
    (34, 78, NULL)
;


CREATE TABLE companies
    ([CompanyId] int, [Name] varchar(9))
;

INSERT INTO companies
    ([CompanyId], [Name])
VALUES
    (45, 'SONY'),
    (66, 'HP'),
    (78, 'MICROSOFT'),
    (99, 'APPLE')
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a join in the `UPDATE` statement:

```
update e
set e.WorkingFor = c.Name
from employees e inner join companies c
on c.CompanyId = e.WorkingForId
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5b66aa59b855198a8233246289e70684).
Results:

```
> EmployeeId | WorkingForId | WorkingFor
> ---------: | -----------: | :---------
>         34 |           45 | SONY      
>         34 |           66 | HP        
>         34 |           78 | MICROSOFT
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple `Update` statment :

```
Update employees 
Set WorkingFor = c.Name
From companies c
Where CompanyId = employees.WorkingForId
```

Out put :

```
EmployeeId  WorkingForId    WorkingFor
34          45              SONY
34          66              HP
34          78              MICROSOFT
```

Comment: This simple update statement is a join with an outdated syntax.